# .deps.json not found executing vs test after vs build in dev ops

Tags: visual-studio, .net-core, azure-devops, msbuild

I can´t past the task "execute test" because this error, in all my tests projects.

*##[error]Unable to find D:\a\13\s$\testcore\obj\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\Project.TestCore.deps.json. Make sure test project has a nuget reference of package "Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk".*

Nuget is installed in the last version and the file deps.json always exist when build in my local machine.

Project is dot net core 3.1

Any ideas? Thank you very much in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> .deps.json not found executing vs test after vs build in dev ops

According to the error message, the `.deps.json` exists in the web application output folder, but it is not copied to the test project output folder.

Please try to reference the nuget package `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Testing` directly from the integration test project.

From the document [ASP.NET Core integration tests](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/integration-tests?view=aspnetcore-5.0#aspnet-core-integration-tests):

> The `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Testing` package handles the following
> tasks:
>
> - **Copies the dependencies file (.deps) from the SUT into the test    project's bin directory.**
> - Sets the content root to the SUT's project root so that static files    and pages/views are found when the tests are executed.
> - Provides the WebApplicationFactory class to streamline bootstrapping    the SUT with TestServer.

**Note:** `deps.json` file may causes this build error if project name has multiple words separated by **whitespace**, please try to rename the project to just one word.

Comment: THANKS!! for your time and your fast response. but have this error when  try install te nuget. 


Error NU1202 El nuget Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Testing 5.0.5 no compatible with netcoreapp3.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.1). El paquete Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Testing 5.0.5 admite: net5.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v5.0) Axesor.MotorCalculo.Shared.Utils.TestCore C:\source\***.TestCore.csproj 1

Comment: @PopeDev, you are install the version 5.0.5, which is for the .NETCoreApp,Version=v5.0, you should try to install the version **3.1.12** instead of 5.0.5.

Comment: I'm having this issue in a `net6.0` xUnit project and I have the `<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Testing" Version="6.0.2" />`

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue with .NET 6 and minimal API

This article helped https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/integration-tests?view=aspnetcore-6.0#basic-tests-with-the-default-webapplicationfactory

The summary is that:

- Your `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Testing` must be compatible with your xUnit project. So if you're using .NET 6, make sure you use some version like 6.x.x
- Your xUnit project MUST have a reference to the WebApi project
- Be careful with the `Startup` or `Program` you're using to build the TestServer. If you're using a minimal Web API you have to expose the `Program.cs` as per link above.

In my case I added this to the Web Api project

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <InternalsVisibleToSuffix Include=".FunctionalTests" /> <!-- THIS LINE to make private classes like Program.cs available to any xUnit project with suffix .FunctionalTests-->
    <ProjectReference Include="..\ExchangeRateCalculation\ExchangeRateCalculation.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Then my minimal API looks like this

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
var app = builder.Build();
app.Map("/", () => "hello world");
app.Run();

// NOTICE this declaration! This is what makes Program.cs available
partial class Program { } // See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/integration-tests?view=aspnetcore-6.0
```

And my TestServer

```
public class SampleTests
{
    private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;

    public CalculateCryptoInEurTests()
    {
        var application =
            new WebApplicationFactory<Program>()
                .WithWebHostBuilder(builder =>
                {
                    builder.ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostingContext, config) =>
                    {
                        var env = hostingContext.HostingEnvironment;

                        config
                            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", true, false)
                            .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", true, false)
                            .AddEnvironmentVariables();

                        if (env.IsDevelopment())
                        {
                            var appAssembly = Assembly.Load(new AssemblyName(env.ApplicationName));
                            config.AddUserSecrets(appAssembly, true);
                        }
                    });
                });

        var client = application.CreateClient();

        _httpClient = client;
    }

    // FACTs using the _httpClient here
}
```